# Can somebody please tell me how to wire this?

Tags: wiringpi, wiring

I litterally cannot find it anywhere on how to wire this

https://www.adafruit.com/product/2934

The only thing any of the pigrrl schematics show is connecting wires from b1,2,3,4 to pins on another board. Last time I checked adafruit, you need a positive and negative pin. This isn't redstone, you can't just connect one wire and hope it works. On top of this bad documentation the stuff isn't even labeled right. All that's labeled is G,G,b1,b2,b3,b4. Wtf is G and why do I have two of them?!?! Where do I connect power and where do I connect ground!?!? Plz help.

Comment: Explain. I don't think you understand my question. I understand they're all switches. What I don't understand is where I need to connect my power ground and what not on to the PCB. If I needed to connect them like any other switch or button then there would be no point in making this.

Comment: So. Again. My question is: where on the PCB do I connect ground and power?

Comment: What's the purpose of two G's ?

Comment: But why two? Also. I'm assuming this would work wiring up the same as for Arduino. Is that correct?

Comment: Sorry. I missed where you said to edit the question. Doing that rn. Also. I don't think I disrespected anybody here. I said adafruits documentation in case you missed that part. Now my next question is, if G is ground obviously, and b1-4 are input pins then where do I connect my power wire to? There needs to be power somewhere of course.

Comment: So then it is not the same as wiring up buttons on an Arduino?

Comment: No no no it is not. I just wired it on an Arduino. The way I learned to wire a button on the Arduino is: 5v (power pin) to leg of button. Other leg of button connects to input pin, as well as to a 10k resistor that's connected to ground. In your way I have a wire going from ground to input(which sounds reversed to me) and in mine I I have a Power pin going to an input pin AND a resistor connected to ground. How are those the same?

Comment: then i suggest that you research all the ways to connect a switch to an arduino ... connecting to +5V is one way  .... in that case connect `G` to +5V and do not connect anything to ground

Comment: On top of those very big differences. There is no power on the raspberry pi wiring you mentioned. The purpose of an input pin is to let power in to be measured, and the purpose of a ground pin is to let power go to ground. For a circuit to work something has to be emmiting power and the ground should be absorbing it, so unless there's a huge Miss understanding here your wiring you mentioned above shouldn't work. That is, if by input pin you mean in the same context as an Arduino. Put your Arduino pin to input and connect it to a button that's connected to ground and tell me what you get

Comment: Jsotola I already atempted setting an arduino pin as input and connecting it to a button and then to ground. Your wiring DOESNT work. Try it yourself. An input pin does not emmit power and neither does a ground pin so please tell me: where is the power source in this wiring example?

Comment: set pin to INPUT_PULLUP ... connect switch between pin and ground  ..... very simple .... no external resistor needed ....  https://www.baldengineer.com/arduino-internal-pull-up-resistor-tutorial.html

Comment: On an Arduino I think they're already set. I can't change them! So how, does this work for an Arduino again...

Comment: look at these two  .... https://grantwinney.com/using-pullup-and-pulldown-resistors-on-the-raspberry-pi/  .......  https://www.baldengineer.com/arduino-internal-pull-up-resistor-tutorial.html

Comment: You're missing my point. All of these require 3 things. A bin, vout, and a ground. Where does  3 things ever equal 2. Your wiring has a ground and a vin. Do you see my point now?

Comment: i am sorry, but this is not going anywhere .... you need to learn the basics of connecting switches to the RPi and to the Arduino .... with internal pullups (pulldowns) you only need 2 connections

Comment: I can connect switches to the Arduino I did 5 minutes ago. I can connect ping sensors and servos and I can even have a raspberry pi monitor the arduinos serial port to send text messages through the terminal. I'm an engineering major in college right now which I know doesn't mean much to you but maybe instead of me needing to understand basic circuits you should understand the basics of explain things to people. I'm sorry I don't understand you but what you need to understand is that everything has to have power from somewhere in a circuit.

Comment: There is NO circuit that does not have a vout except yours and I fail to see how it works. Forgive me for my missunderstanding.

Comment: In the very first example he uses two pins to make a switch just like you did. Only he has a 3.3v power pin connected to his switch and then to a resistor and then to the input pin. You told me I need a ground pin connected to the button then to the resistor and then to the input pin. So you see the difference now? Do you see how the circuit you told me to do will NOT work.

Comment: On top of all of this. You completely miss the topic of this question. Which is: how do I wire this PCB up? If you can't help then you shouldn't answer. If you can't explain then don't confuse people more.

Comment: You appear to be trying to have an argument with yourself in Comments. Edit your question for additional detail.

Answer (score 2):

This is labeled as a difficult project, so you have to know what you're doing.

However, just from my experience and the labling of the board, the G is ground, and the B buttons go to the pins for each button. The software should set the internal resisters on.

As for the two ground connectors, it is necessary to have a good connection to ground, and this allows you solder the same wire twice.

Why would you think that "G" denoted a wireless connector?

Comment: I assumed it was ground but wasn't positive and I just needed to know how to wire the PCB. I'm not taking that.

Answer (score 1):

here are four different ways to connect the switches

i showed only two switches, but you can expand to any number

the internal pullups/pulldowns are built into the microcontroller and must be enabled in the program

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWeQ1Y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: So then what you're saying is with an Arduino we use the external pull-up but with the raspberry pi we use the internal pull up?

Comment: no!!!!! .... RPi can use all four circuits ..... Arduino can use three (it does not have the internal pulldowns option) ....... i strongly suggest that you research all the ways to connect a switch to an arduino and RPi

Comment: I'm sorry. I worded that wrong what I meant to say is the Arduino doesn't have internal resistors so it can only use the external wiring diagrams you finely provided but the raspberry pi on the other hand does have internal resistors so it can use either of the four. My bad my bad. Bad wording on my part 

Comment: I understand now. See. I knew the raspberry pi had internal pull ups and downs but I forgot about them for the circuits. That's why I was so confused when you only said 2 parts of the circuit. It's because I forgot about the internal resistors.

Comment: all the arduinos have internal pullups ... also, have a look at the links that i posted

Comment: I did look at the first one. Ill give number 2 a read tomorrow. Thank you for the help!!!